# Npm doesn't see the newest npm package version

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Hay,

I have some big problems with sub-dependencies.

I have **react-test-renderer** package which uses **react-is** package.

And the problem starts here. Because of **react-is** want to be installed on version **16.3.1**

But when I want to install only "react-is@16.3.1" then npm tells me that package version is not existing: 
[image: npm install error message]

Also tried "**npm view react-is**" command to view if that version already exist:
[image: npm view react-is versions]

The funniest thing is that, when I go to the npmjs.com page and look for the react-is version, there is a version 16.3.1 published 8h ago:

[image]

And When I type **npm install** command I got an error about not existing react-is version: 
[image: npm install errors]

When I use **yarn install** then I can simply choose the existing version and everything works correctly: 
[image: yarn install choose]

But I can't use yarn on the production and I need to solve it somehow by using npm.

Maybe have you some idea, how should I solve this?

Comment: I have tryied _npm info react-is_ and I can see version 16.3.1 and _npm install react-is@16.3.1_ installs it correctly

Comment: So maybe it is somehow cached.In my npm info react-is there is no 16.3.1 version.

Comment: Yeah I would suggest to _npm cache clean --force_

Comment: I did it and it doesn't help me also :(

Comment: Things I would try are: update npm to latest  _npm install npm@latest -g_ and try in a clean node_modules folder. No more ideas :-(

Comment: Did all of this. No effects :(

Comment: Could you post your package.json and your npm version.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same bug right now. Just try to upgrade your version one more time (in your case to 16.13.**2**). This should solve the problem. Maybe something is going wrong during package publication with `npm publish`

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue. I could see the latest version of my package correctly published but every attempt to npm install failed. For me the solution was to clear the cache using **npm cache clean --force** after which **npm install** worked. Hope this helps anyone else having same issue

Comment: Yep, solved it for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and then I found out I had a custom repository in the .npmrc file. Deleting it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found out through `npm info x` that npm-package `x` was not showing the expected latest version. I then found out that I had an `.npmrc` custom registry config that messed that up. Removing it, installing the package, and then using the `.npmrc` again solved the problem for me.